# Increasing memory limit composer

Tags: php, memory, composer-php

Executed this command, but the help menu for composer is getting displayed

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer
```

this is the in the directory where the composer file is located (the bin directory). tried with composer.phar, says file does not exist.
please help. thank you

Comment: if there is a different solution to change the environment variable memory limit, please suggest

Comment: What you're expecting from this command? You didn't call any composer command, so displaying help is expecting action.

Comment: I want to increase the memory limit of the composer environment variable. a help file suggested this command
"
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar
"
but i tried to execute the command in the directory where composer is supposed to be executing from, the file does not exist. so i am not sure where to find the .phar file. which from i know is an executable. but yet the command does not seem to find it

Comment: It does not change any environment variable, `-d memory_limit=-1` disables memory limit for *this* command call. It does not have any persistent effects.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

Comment: can you take a look at that section and help me increase the memory limit.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on the document, you should be able to add a composer command in the <...>

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer <...>
```

So, for things like

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer require apackage
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update
```

That means to run the composer command with memory_limit = -1.

Comment: thnak you for the help :)

Comment: On running the command it gives -> Could not open input file: composer